# Why is Xcode 7 iOS Simulator freezing?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, xcode7

I'm getting odd freezes of up to 60s in the Xcode 7 simulator, specifically when scrolling or doing other GPU-intensive tasks. The problem appears to be with the simulator as a whole, not my app (lots of spinning beach ball, slow to respond to rotate commands, etc.).

If I track CPU time in Instruments, 50s of real time shows as below 0.5s of CPU time for my app.

What's going on? (El Cap, Xcode 7.1, all iOS versions, all devices)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I run Better Snap Tool for window management. Quitting this app (or disabling it from interacting with the simulator) fixes the problem immediately, even if the sim is in the middle of a freeze. No idea why, but Better Snap Tool appears to be interfering with iOS Simulator's use of the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. If you could leave some feedback on why this factually correct and relevant answer doesn't cut the mustard for you, that'd be greeeeaaaat.

Comment: thanks - this was bugging the hell out of me. Let's see if El Capitan finally has a decent built in replacement for what BetterSnapTool provides me with (happy user for 4+ years!)

Comment: I'm not sure why it works; perhaps some accessibility bugs in 10.11. I had other apps like for window management I had to disable to get the simulator to run w/o beach balls and delays.

Comment: This works for me, I was also seeing the bug on Yosemite

Comment: Seems to also be the case with Moom.

Comment: Wow, how did you find this out?

Comment: @ReyGonzales honestly, luck. I spent a while being really confused, and then was staring at it, saw the BetterSnapTool icon in the menu and had a brainwave which turned out to be correct!

Comment: Would have never guessed, continued to blame Apple but glad you found the culprit!